# Qt: the same font looks different being rendered in QML and c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qfont

QML and c++ code use the same font.

QML:

```
TextEdit {  
        ...                  
        font: settings.font // font.preferShaping = false doesn't help
        ...
        renderType: Text.QtRendering // Text.NativeRendering also doesn't paint correctly
    }
```

letters (corners are rounded):

[image]

C++:

```
QSGNode* Text::updatePaintNode(QSGNode* oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData*)
{
    ...
    QImage image(QSize(size, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    QPainter painter(&image);
    //painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform); doesn't help also
    image.fill(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
    painter.setFont(settings.font());
    painter.drawText(rect, alignment(), text));
    ...
}
```

letters (sharp corners):

[image]

Update:
the code below also doesn't fix the corners in QML:

```
font.family: "Segoe UI"
font.pixelSize: 15
font.preferShaping: false
```

How can I synchronize looking of the fonts between QML and c++ ?

---

Windows 10, tested on Qt 5.15.8 msvc2019 & Qt 6.5.0 msvc2019
Reproducible example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 640
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "#303030"
        width: textEdit.contentWidth
        height: textEdit.contentHeight

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            color: "yellow"
            font.family: "Segoe UI"
            font.pointSize: 300
            font.preferShaping: false
            text: "Й"
        }
    }
}
```

result (rounded corners):

[image]

Comment: Is this true only for that particular font? Or does the same thing happen with all fonts?

Comment: What is your OS? If you're on Windows, have you tried to add `-platform windows:fontengine=freetype` to your command line?

Comment: @JarMan it is true for all the fonts

Comment: @Atmo OS Win 10 x64. `-platform windows:fontengine=freetype` doesn't help too

Comment: `font: settings.font` does not work. I mentioned this problem in another of your questions. One sure way of creating a font object in QML is is using https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#font-method

Comment: thanks, but the line `font: Qt.font({ pixelSize: getFont().pixelSize, family: getFont().family, preferShaping: false })` also doesn't fix the issue

Comment: So I've tested it on Windows and Linux (Qt 6.5) with `Text.NativeRendering` and it doesn't draw rounded corners as with`Text.QtRendering`. What do you mean by native rendering doesn't paint correctly?

Comment: For what it's worth I reproed the OP's question with `TextEdit { font.family: "Segoe UI"; font.pixelSize: 450; text: "ON"; color: "yellow" }` and like @iam_peter observed, using `Text.NativeRendering` doesn't draw rounded corners as with `Text.QtRendering`. According to the documentation, you may wish to use `renderType: Text.NativeRendering` in combination with `font.hintingPreference`.

Comment: Please show the result of using `Text.NativeRendering`.

Comment: If you use `Text`, there is also a `renderTypeQuality` option available to fix issues with glyph quality. However, in `TextEdit`, this option does not exist, and it appears that you must continue using the default quality. Additionally, I have encountered issues with `QtRendering`, and `NativeRendering` does not display anything for point sizes greater than 220 (in my experience).

Comment: To complete my last comment, the `QQuickTextNode` is responsible for painting glyphs. Its private member, `m_renderTypeQuality`, has a default hardcoded value of `-1` [[1](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quick/items/qquicktextnode.cpp#L36)]. Setting other values is only possible using the [setRenderTypeQuality](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quick/items/qquicktextnode_p.h#L75) function, which is not used in `TextEdit` [[2](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quick/items/qquicktextedit.cpp)].

Comment: Do you have any graphic card?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R yes I have GeForce GTX 750

Answer (score 0):

You can antialias the TextEdit text in QML by using the `renderType` property.

Setting the `renderType` to `TextEdit.NativeRendering` enables **antialiasing** on the text, which **smooths** out the edges of the characters.

I just add `renderType: TextEdit.NativeRendering` to your qml code :

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 640
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "#303030"
        width: textEdit.contentWidth
        height: textEdit.contentHeight

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            color: "yellow"
            font.family: "Segoe UI"
            font.pointSize: 300
            font.preferShaping: false
            renderType: TextEdit.NativeRendering
            text: "Й"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is its Result:

[image]

Comment: OP used `NativeRendering`, and it did not help: (_renderType: Text.QtRendering // Text.NativeRendering also doesn't paint correctly_). `NativeRendering` depends on the platform, you're on Ubuntu, OP's on Windows.

Comment: I've also tested `NativeRendering` on windows and ubuntu and it worked the same. OP didn't really clarify what they meant by "doesn't paint correctly"...

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene but it will change for me , maybe this relates to graphic cards, I test in fedora 38 and Qt 6.5 and Nvidia GPU.antialiasing is dependent on the operating system and hardware, so the results may vary across different devices

Comment: @iam_peter I think  it's not smooth in Second Picture and he wants what he draws with paint in c++. But do you have graphic card? And what was your results in both os ? Was it smooth?

Comment: I think, "antialias" isn't quite the right word here because the rendered glyph itself is already antialiased. It just appears deformed due to the optimization of the glyph shape.

Comment: @SMR well I mean it will smooth by TextEdit.NativeRendering  as I show in picture. Unfortunately I don't have windows os right now but I will test there as soon as I can. I just wanted to show OP that it works as he said "Text.NativeRendering also doesn't paint correctly" and maybe that issue relates to his OS.

Comment: It has already been tested on Windows, and it works as well.